# Regex that either matches a string OR returns a non empty value

Tags: regex

I am writing Regex for a REST API where specific numeric values upto five decimal places are extracted by API. I am trying to write a regex that either matches alphanumeric value or returns a non empty value if no match is found. The alpha numeric values are in a lengthy string. A block of string example is below:

```
,"circulatingSupply":18687562,"totalSupply":18687562,"maxSupply":21000000,"marketCapDominance":50.5442,"
```

We need maxsupply numeric value so I successfully built the regex to extract the numeric value:

```
/\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\"/
```

But the problem is that the substring may or may not be present. If the string is not present then the regex should return non empty value (not a NULL value or undefined value). I tried following but couldn't get a working regex as all are being rejected by the REST API:

```
/\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\"|([ ])/
/(?:\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\")?/
/\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\"|( )/
/(?:\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\"){0,1}/
```

I tried using OR operator but i think I am having a problem in Right Hand Side operand of OR operator. The required substring is necessarily in the middle of the large string so I guess ^ and $ will not be of any use. To emphasize, I repeat that if substring is not present then the regex should return non empty value say zero or a space character.

Comment: Here I am not referring any engine because the regex pattern need to be supplied to the REST API as input.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by returning. A regex matches, or it does not match. Using an alternation `|` means that it tries the pattern after it if the first one did not match.

Comment: In second part of alteration, can we write a regex that always matches a string as produced above? Then maybe we can capture non empty values (zero or single space). May be its foolish idea I don't know.

Comment: Maybe you want to just add an alternative to match end of string? `/\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\"|$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: what should I do if the string is multiline?

Comment: Are you programming in Ruby? What is the code behind this regex?

Comment: I am using Perl.

Comment: Well, I am not sure why you need to do that with regex in Perl, where you have all the code at your hand. Not sure how you are using the regex. If you simply have a multiline string and you read it correctly and pass as a whole to the regex, the very end of string is `\z` in Perl: `/\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]*\,\"|\z/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from somewhere. I did the following thing and I got the desired result. It was all about capture group and OR operator placement.

```
$_ =~ /(?:\,\"maxSupply\"\:([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,5}[0-9])*\,\"|(No Data))/
```

Comment: Previously I asked question with different approach and it got closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67183218/regular-expression-that-matches-both-occurrence-and-non-occurrence-of-a-string-b